# change the size of back arrow in actionbar android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have used a picture in the actionbar for  back arrow  but I want to resize the picture height and width which is shown below: how I can change the size of that. Also I attached the xml file as well

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
     <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/images</item>
```

[image]

Comment: Just use setLogo(R.drawable.images) in codes.Or android:logo in theme.

Comment: well i asked to change the height and width of that inside the app like android:layout_height function, is there any function to be usable for action bar as well?

Comment: @user3669034, I added a post. If you still not feel satisfied, please tell me and I would edit my post to find another solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have `actionbar.xml` layout file containing this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_details"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_very_small"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_medium"
            android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/dimen_medium"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_details"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And you want to change size of view with id 'action_bar_back'. Here it's `ImageButton`, but 'ImageView' also would be good. You can do it i many ways:

- change `layout_width` and `layout_height` with exact value like `60dp`
- scale an image using `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `scaleType`. It uses `float` values.
- use this great tool: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/ to generate some needed sizes of image and put them in `drawable-[density]` folders

  - using programs like `GIMP` to resize the picture to desired size

Hope this article would be useful: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)